# Introductory Problem on Markov's Inequality

Tags: statistics

Here is the question I'm interested in answering with the most basic version of Markov's Inequality:

Can you bound the probability that at most 10 heads show up from 100 flips of a fair coin?

I pretty sure I'm using Markov's Inequality correctly, but I'm encountering a meaningless lower bound. I know from experience this is certainly possible. Just here to get my worked checked.

Let $X \sim B(100,\frac{1}{2})$ count the number of heads that appear from flipping a fair coin 100 times. Then
$$P(X\le10)=1-P(X\ge11) \ge1-\frac{E(X)}{11}=1-\frac{50}{11}=-\frac{39}{11}.$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your work is right, and so is your suspicion that the Markov inequality is meaningless here.

Note however that if you use symmetry of the distribution you can bound the probability above in a more meaningful (although still terribly conservative) way, since $P(X \leq 10) = P(X\geq 90) \leq \frac{50}{90}$.

You can also bound $P(X \geq 11)$ below by $P(X \geq 11) = P(X \leq 89) = 1- P(X \geq 90) \geq 1 - \frac{50}{90}$.

Again, these are terrible bounds, but they do point to a general rule of thumb: the Markov inequality will give lower bounds probabilities of events concentrated near the mean, and upper bounds for the outskirts of the distribution.  This is also true of, and even more apparent from, Chebyshev's inequality.